# FatalErrorException: ParameterBag in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I just installed Symfony2 in my local server using XAMPP, and fixed all the recommendation extensions- APC and intl. 
When I tried to access `http://localhost/symblog/web/app_dev.php/`. I got the following error.

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class
>   'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag' not
>   found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symblog/app/bootstrap.php.cache
>   line 2469

I don't know what's wrong with it. I try to googling but It doesn't have any information. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you cache is broken or dependencies are missing. Try:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

If nothing changes, try:

```
php composer.phar install
```